# html5 audio api - frequencyBinCount does not return anything on Safari

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api

Trying to create a javascript visualizer, but Safari is not acting nice. The audio data is all blank.

This is my code below -

http://jsbin.com/olugOri/1/edit

Chrome works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually because they haven't *really* implemented `MediaElementSourceNode` yet. No matter how you use it (with a gain node, with a script processor, whatever) it always spits out zeroes.

You're not doing anything wrong, Safari just hasn't implemented it yet.

Comment: aw ok, that sucks :( it's already version 7 would have been nice to od it already

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this is the issue, but you probably shouldn't be calling the analyser functions from within onaudioprocess.  onaudioprocess needs to be a super-tight function.  If you just want a visual volume averaging, use requestAnimationFrame to show an average volume from an analyser; you only need a scriptprocessor if you're trying to detect clipping.